# Soft keyboard causes view to bounce in flex mobile app

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, bounce, soft-keyboard

Have a flex mobile app with a couple of text inputs set up in a login form. When the soft keyboard appears the view pans up but then "un-pans" and "re-pans" giving this strange bounce effect.

Does anyone know how or why?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I ended up resolving it by changing the `softKeyboardBehavior` property in my app.xml to `none` instead of `pan`. I prefer the look of the default `pan`, but none works too, and without the bouncing.

Comment: I filed a bug for this and they refuse to fix it, despite being able to reproduce it. They asked for votes in order to even bother taking a look at it. Please vote it up: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3345104